# jQuery two dropdown menus? (dynamically)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

if I have two dropdowns such as:

```
<select>
<option value="option1">option 1</option>
<option value="option2">option 2</option>
<option value="option3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

followed by:

```
<select>
<option value="option5">option 5</option>
<option value="option8">option 8</option>
<option value="option9">option 9</option>
</select>
```

how can i make it so that if from the first dropdown someone selects option 2 that only option 9 is available from the second dropdown?
I was told i would need to store the values but am a bit lost on all this?

Thanks for any help.

John

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the options hidden or disabled. You said disabled but folks are hiding options.

Comment: where u need to store. tell clearly.. what u need?

Comment: Remember to up vote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/VLvYA/

Disabled as requested and also auto selects option.

```
$('#first-select').change(function(){
    $('#second-select option').prop('disabled',false);
    if(this.value == 'option2')
        $('#second-select option:not([value="option9"])')
            .prop('disabled',true).parent().val('option9');

});​
```

Comment: OP doesn't request them to be *disabled*

Comment: OP doesn't request them to be disabled or hidden only un-selectable.

Comment: But you said *disabled as requested*, he didn't request them to be *disabled* specifically, only un-selectable.

Comment: @iambriansreed Can you explain un-selectable without disabling/hiding/removing?

Comment: The OP didn't say *disabled* per se, but he said "...only option 9 is available..." which I took to mean available to select. Not necessarily hiding other options. It's why I asked for clarification. If he wanted the options to be removed would he have said so?

Comment: This demo seems to do exactly what I am after - will try it when I get home then set it as the correct answer, many thanks!

Comment: @John Awesome. I hope it works out. Glad you could see past the crazy voting.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to remove 2nd drop down options based on the option selected index from drop down 1.

**EDIT:** Removed extra clone that was not required.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xVNTs/2/)

```
$(function () {
    var $dd2Opt = $('#dd2 option').clone();
    var $dd2 = $('#dd2');
    $('#dd1').change(function () {
        $dd2.empty().append($dd2Opt.slice(this.selectedIndex + 1));
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="dd1">
  <option value="option1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="dd2">
  <option value="option5">option 5</option>
  <option value="option8">option 8</option>
  <option value="option9">option 9</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var opts = $('select.second option');
$('select:first').on('change',function() {
  if(this.value == 'option2') {
     $(this).next('select.second').empty().append(opts[this.selectedIndex + 1]).change();
  } else {
    $(this).next('select.second').empty().append(opts).change();
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
<option value="option1">option 1</option>
<option value="option2">option 2</option>
<option value="option3">option 3</option>
</select>
<select class="second">
<option value="option5">option 5</option>
<option value="option8">option 8</option>
<option value="option9">option 9</option>
</select>
```

**[Live Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/fgrvK/1/)**

Comment: Now try selecting anything else from the first select. :(

Comment: Removed the down vote. A whole lot of unnecessary DOM manipulation though.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainSelect').live('change', function () {
                $('#subSelect option').hide();
                $('#subSelect option[data-option="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
                $('#subSelect option:visible:first').attr('selected', true);
            });

            $('#mainSelect').trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mainSelect">
        <option value="option1">option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="subSelect">
        <option value="option5" data-option="option1">option 5</option>
        <option value="option8" data-option="option3">option 8</option>
        <option value="option9" data-option="option2">option 9</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ThulasiRam Just post only the relevant code. See other answers format as a reference.